# How to Stop LowLevelKeyboardProc from Writing the Key

Tags: c#

I am writing a program to mess the keys on the keyboard (if you press A then K will be written). All works great but I have a problem where when you write (as in the example) A it will write KA. So the program write what I want but also the user's input.

Here is the function:

```
private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    // My keyboard messing is here
    return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I initially thought the way to make Windows not write the key was to change the return. I have changed it, removed it and even change the info in the paramaters I am passing and nothing seem to work.

My question is: how do I make it so the OS won't write what the user pressed?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was actually pretty simple. Rather than returning the `CallNextHookEx` function I should have returned `(IntPtr)1`